# Middleware "strapi::session": App keys are required. Please set app.keys in config/server.js (ex: keys: ['myKeyA', 'myKeyB'])

Tags: javascript, strapi, cloudinary

Trying to set up strapi and cloudinary
I watched two videos and they are all OK, but I have an error, tell me why?

> Middleware "strapi::session": App keys are required. Please set
> app.keys in config/server.js (ex: keys: ['myKeyA', 'myKeyB'])

[image]

plugins.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  // ...
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: 'cloudinary',
      providerOptions: {
        cloud_name: env('CLOUDINARY_NAME'),
        api_key: env('CLOUDINARY_KEY'),
        api_secret: env('CLOUDINARY_SECRET'),
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

.env

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=1337
CLOUDINARY_NAME="my data"
CLOUDINARY_KEY="my data"
CLOUDINARY_SECRET="my data"
JWT_SECRET=my data
```

server.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
});
```

middlewares.js

```
module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
  'strapi::security',
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```

admin.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  auth: {
    secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET'),
  },
  apiToken: {
    salt: env('API_TOKEN_SALT'),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `APP_KEYS` defined in your `.env` file (assuming you're sharing the full file), as well as some other env variables you're accessing using strapi's built in env utility.

In your `.env` you should have a value for the following that should follow this format:

```
APP_KEYS=['key1','key2']
```

You can read more about environment config from Strapi's development docs:
https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/optional/environment.html#strapi-s-environment-variables

Comment: why in this video he doesn't use it too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2rQPEeL9FU&t=341s 7:20

Comment: and if I do that I got new error Missing apiToken.salt. Please set apiToken.salt in config/admin.js (ex: you can generate one using Node with `crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')`).

Comment: ok I just added API_TOKEN_SALT and ADMIN_JWT_SECRET else and all work

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick kotlin script to generate the necessary environment variables for Strapi. **For security reasons, you should run this locally**. But you can of course run it on [play.kotlin.org](https://pl.kotl.in/GiZfRwSf6). You can put the output of this script in your `.env` file.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.util.Base64

fun main() {

    val rnd = SecureRandom()

    val appKeys = List(4) {
        val buffer = ByteArray(16)
        rnd.nextBytes(buffer)
        Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(buffer)
    }

    val buffer = ByteArray(16)
    rnd.nextBytes(buffer)
    var jwtSecret = buffer.joinToString("") { String.format("%02x", it) }
    jwtSecret = jwtSecret.substring(0, 8) + "-" + jwtSecret.substring(8, 12) + "-" + jwtSecret.substring(12, 16) + "-" + jwtSecret.substring(16)

    rnd.nextBytes(buffer)
    val apiTokenSalt = buffer.joinToString("") { String.format("%02x", it) }

    println("APP_KEYS=" + appKeys.joinToString(","))
    println("JWT_SECRET=$jwtSecret")
    println("API_TOKEN_SALT=$apiTokenSalt")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue create a `.env` file which should be a copy of `.env.example`. Depending on your version of Strapi you may need to add more environment variables. Then use Node in the terminal to run `crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')` commands, after running the command you will get a generated key to use in the `.env`

Here's an example of a working `.env` file, just swap `generatedKey` with your crypto keys.

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=1337
APP_KEYS=['generatedKey1', 'generatedKey2']
JWT_SECRET=generatedKey3
API_TOKEN_SALT=generatedKey4
ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=generatedKey5
```